# Github /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcap: No such file or directory

Tags: github, rust, github-actions, libpcap

I have a small rust project in Github and I added a rust.yml file for the actions to build the project and run the tests automatically.

The build crashes while Compiling `libc v0.2.153` with the following note:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcap: No such file or directory
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The yml file I'm using for the actions is the basic rust one that Github provides

```
name: Rust

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

env:
  CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Build
      run: cargo build --verbose
    - name: Run tests
      run: cargo test --verbose
```

Do I need to add some libraries or paths to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by simply installing the library.

Just added this to the jobs build section of the YAML file before the build:

```
    - name: Install libpcap
      run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libpcap-dev
```